# Handle MouseEnter over Commands in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I have a Canvas with ItemControl filled in ViewModel with Custom UserControlViewModels. I want to give every UserControl a MouseEnter Command or something.

My XAML of my ViewModel is the following:

```
<Canvas x:Name="gameFieldCanvas" Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}" Height="{Binding CanvasHeight}">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameFieldContent}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GameFieldTileViewModel}">
             <Canvas>
                <local:GameFieldTileUserControl X="{Binding TileX}" Y="{Binding TileY}">
                   <local:GameFieldTileUserControl.InputBindings>
                      <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.OnGameFieldTileLeftClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                      <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.OnGameFieldTileRightClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                   </local:GameFieldTileUserControl.InputBindings>
                </local:GameFieldTileUserControl>
             </Canvas>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Like you can see I have already Command for Left-/RightClick that working fine. But there is no InputBindings for MouseEnterEvents.

I already read about that Blend SDK where you can write EventTriggers or something like that, but isn't it possible with board tools?

I just want to realize when a UserControl is entered an get the UserControlViewModel of it.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Because of handle MouseEvents in ViewModel? I want to manipulate the `GameFieldContent` so I need the Commands in the ViewModel of the canvas. Is there a better way?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, so I can't really judge. All I can say is that this smells. Your UI should only communicate to your VM your user's intent, then update in response to changes in the VM's state. You appear to be transmitting mouse input into the view model where the interpretation of intent is being made. That should be done in the UI. Anyhow, keep that in mind while thinking about your design. Good luck.

Comment: I know that. Theory and practice are not always compatible, at least I do not always see the way. The Problem is I have an `MapViewModel` of my `MapView`, including canvas filled with `GameFieldViewModels` representing `GameFieldTiles` in View. How is it helpful to have `MouseEventHandler` in every `GameFieldViewModel` when I want the action happen in the `MapViewModel`. I mean don't missunderstand me, all I want to have are the "which Tile was entered/clicked etc." to know which of the models I have to change. The changes then take place in the model who call the `PropertyChanged` methods.

Comment: Uh wow, that sounds nice, really! I'm new to wpf/c# since a couple of weeks, so I don't know the tricks. And I think even after your description I am not able to implement that correctly. Maybe you want to post an answer with a more detailed description and some codesnippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give me detail about what you want to accomplish in the end?  I may have a better answer for you depending but you can, and I have many times, overridden existing controls and added the command properties needed.

Here's a custom user control that has mouse move commands.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPF_Question_Answer_App
{
    public partial class MouseMoveCommandUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MouseMoveCommandUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MouseMove += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (MouseMoveCommand?.CanExecute(MouseMoveCommandParameter) ?? false)
                    MouseMoveCommand.Execute(MouseMoveCommandParameter);
            };
        }

        public ICommand MouseMoveCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MouseMoveCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseMoveCommandUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object MouseMoveCommandParameter
        {
            get => GetValue(MouseMoveCommandParameterProperty);
            set => SetValue(MouseMoveCommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MouseMoveCommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(MouseMoveCommandUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

And here's using in in the view which is obvious.

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Question_Answer_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Question_Answer_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:MouseMoveCommandUserControl MouseMoveCommand="{Binding SomeMouseMoveCommand}"
                                           MouseMoveCommandParameter="{Binding SomeMouseMoveCommandParameter}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hopefully this helps... If not I'll remove the answer just let me know.

Comment: thank you for providing your code. I have to write an Application to build a Map out of Tiles(`GameFieldTileViewModel`). Initial the Map will be filled with `GrassfieldTiles`. Additional I have a WrapPanel filled with possible tiles(`PlaseableObject`) to place. After clicking one of that `PlaseableObject` I generate a new `GameFieldTileViewModel` and added it to my `GameFieldContent` Collection. Now I want to change its X/Y coordinates to the X/Y coordinates of the `GrassfieldTiles` I entered with the mouse, so I want to have a `MouseEnterCommand` with the entered Tile as param.

Comment: If PlaseableObject or GrassfieldTiles is the control you're adding to the WrapPanel and you want a MouseMoveCommand on those then just copy and paste the DependencyProperties I've given above into those controls.  Then add the MouseMove event in the constructor to attempt firing the command, and finally bind the command to the control just like you would any other normal command.  When the mouse moves in the control he command will fire (or test to fire).

Comment: Yeah but how can I bind that `GameFieldTileViewModel` to the `MouseMoveCommandParameter`? When I make that like I do in the `MouseBinding` I get `NullReferenceException` at `if (MouseMoveCommand.CanExecute(MouseMoveCommandParameter))`
 when entering the tile

Comment: Oh stop! Now I have it! I just forgot something! Thank you! You safed my day! =)

Comment: Hey again! I managed to replicate your Code for `MouseWheel`, how do I need to customize that code to get the direction of `MouseWheel` through the Command?

Comment: You just test the direction and make a command for each... MouseWheelPositiveCommand / MouseWheelNegativeCommand or however named you prefer.  Just have a specific command for each and in the event test and fire the appropriate command.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of how it can be accomplished using built in components..

You can leverage UI components that already exist to accomplish most of your goals. There are side effects (can't click on the same tile twice in a row, need to modify how selection behaves, etc), but it's another way of doing things.

In your window, use an ListBox with an appropriate panel. In my example, you could use this as a basis for a tic tac toe game:

```
<Window x:Class="TileClicker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TileClicker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTile}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid
                    Rows="3"
                    Columns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

The window's codebehind is minimal

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

with our tile being represented by

```
public class Tile : Notifier
{
    private string _name = "Click me";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set { _name = value; Notify(); }
    }
}
```

and our view model using the SelectedItem binding to know when a tile is clicked, responding appropriately

```
public class ViewModel : Notifier
{
    private Tile _tile;
    public ObservableCollection<Tile> Tiles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Tile> {
        new Tile(), new Tile(), new Tile(), 
        new Tile(), new Tile(), new Tile(), 
        new Tile(), new Tile(), new Tile()
    };
    public Tile SelectedTile
    {
        get
        {
            return _tile;
        }
        set
        {
            _tile = value;
            Notify();
            UpdateName(value);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateName(Tile value)
    {
        if(value.Name == "Click me")
            value.Name = "Woot!";
        else
            value.Name = "Click me";
    }
}
```

The base just removes the INPC impl from the above classes to ease reading

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Notify([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks good I think. But has that ListBox Control the same possiblities like a canvas, adding all kinds of UserControls with explicit X and Y coordinates etc.? Usually that ListControls have some kind of element formatting or not? I will try that tomorrow!

Comment: @kuemme01 You can use a Canvas instead of a UniformGrid as your panel, and you can configure the ItemTemplate to bind the X and Y coordinates of each model to Canvas.X and Canvas.Y.  I've done that before, and it works flawlessly.